# Option from WebList gets selected and then gets deselected

Tags: list, qtp, hp-uft

Here I have an odd issue where the option of a Weblist control gets selected and then gets deselected immediately. I am unable to figure of why

The code is just selecting an option from WebList. It's a People Soft application if that will help

```
B("B").P("P").F("F").Weblist("Weblist").Select Option
```

When I run the script from the control and break the run in the next line of code, it selects the option which is intended but when I run the whole script it selects and deselects the option immediately.
When manually run in the same sequence, the test case works just fine too

I tried Sync, explicit wait after selecting the option. Also tried to click on the object and use Shell script to select the option. Nothing works for the complete script though everything works when I ran the script from the Object

Has anyone come across a similar issue or have an idea on what is causing the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have. Use `FireEvent` method before selecting from `WebList`. This solved my problem.

```
Browser().Page.WebList().FireEvent("onclick")
Browser().Page.WebList().Select data
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Browser().Page.WebList().Select "#0"
```

This worked for me